# Can we find inradius from medians of a triangle?

Tags: geometry

My question is

Three medians of a triangle are 3 cm and 4  cm and 5 cm. What will be inradius of this triangle?

Can we find inradius?

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inradius.html

Answer (score 2):

Due to Stewart's theorem the squared lengths of the medians are given by
$$ m_a^2 = \frac{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}{4} $$
and so on, so by solving the associated equations in terms of $a^2,b^2,c^2$ we get:
$$ a = \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{73},\qquad b=\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{13},\qquad c=\frac{10}{3}.$$
The inradius is given by $r=\frac{2\Delta}{a+b+c}$, where $\Delta$ can be computed through Heron's formula.

Another trick is the following: the area of $ABC$ is $\frac{4}{3}$ of the area of the triangle whose side lengths are $m_a,m_b,m_c$, hence $\Delta=\color{red}{8}$.

Comment: Sir i could not get your first reply...how to use meadins to get sides a, b and c.. can you please elaborate

Comment: @NeerajSharma You have to solve 3 simultaneous equations from the above formula from Stewart's theorem for the values of $m_a=3,m_b=4$ and $m_c=5$ to find $a,b,c$.